# NULL arrays get converted to empty arrays when written to a table

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run this query below I get 7 as expected.

```
WITH Items AS (
  SELECT [] AS num1, CAST(NULL AS ARRAY<INTEGER>) as num2
)
SELECT COALESCE(num2, [7]) FROM Items;
```

When I save `Items` to a table and then reference the table by name I get `[]` instead, which I  confirmed is not a NULL with the WHERE clause.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE Items
AS
(
  SELECT [] AS num1, CAST(NULL AS ARRAY<INTEGER>) as num2
);

WITH t as
(
  SELECT COALESCE(num2, [7]) as test FROM Items
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE array_length(test)=0
```

Is this expected behavior?
This link suggests empty arrays and NULL arrays are distinct https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#array_nulls

Answer (score 1):

I talked to someone and he pointed out this important statement (emphasis mine):

> **BigQuery translates a NULL ARRAY into an empty ARRAY in the query result**,
> although inside the query, NULL and empty ARRAYs are two distinct values.

It was also news to him but basically it seems when you write to a table you are writing the query result so the NULL ARRAY is now an empty array.

The work around is to use `CREATE VIEW` so that the NULLs are part of the query.